# Ways to reduce buffer if it passes through a certain layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I am trying to do WiFi analysis on signal strength in ArcGIS Desktop, and one of the big problems that I am running into is how to reduce the signal when it comes in contact with a wall, as it does in real life. I would like to use buffers for their visual effects over rasters, but I will use anything that can accurately display what I want. Ultimately I would like to be able to add construction materials to the reduction, but just recognizing the walls in the buffer would be a good start. I am open to solutions within current ArcGIS tools, or python. I have started to create a python toolbox to do this, so either solution would work for me. Any ideas on how to get my buffers to recognize walls?

Comment: Radio propagation is actually very well studied, but is not trivial to implement.  Have you looked into existing models, rather than trying to implement your own?  Do you have formal accuracy requirements?  If you're completely new to propagation models, this site has a very succinct introduction which is about as beginner-friendly as it gets: http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~jones/es151/prop_models/propagation.html

Comment: The purpose of this is to use ArcGIS Desktop to be able to produce our own model. So I have looked at other models to get ideas, but the goal is to bring the ideas generated into ArcGIS.

Comment: Do you have access to a Spatial Analyst license?  What are your accuracy requirements?

Comment: Fully Licensed for all Extensions, and this is all exploratory so the accuracy requirements are pretty relaxed right now, once a technique is established it can be refined further for higher accuracy.

Comment: Cool, I'm putting something together for you.  Do you mind sharing or describing your 'walls' data?

Comment: The wall data that I have is currently lines from the initial CAD drawing, that was brought into and dissolved in ArcGIS to eliminate doors that are normally open during regular hours. Since I am using ArcGIS Pro I extruded them in in 3D, however, that is not quite as relevant for the scale of what I am trying to do.

Comment: It is in line format.

Comment: Do you have attribute information like material and width?

Comment: Not yet, the goal is to include construction material and thickness, but I am looking to see if this can be done first before trying to get too involved with it. I am going to be receiving that information soon, so those are both things that will be included eventually.

Comment: Rather than having a discussion in comments, I think you should consider using the **[edit]** button to revise your original question in light of any learnings that have come to light so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that I have found to do this is to create a raster of a propagation that does not penetrate the walls (walls are listed as no data) and then propagation as if the walls didn't exist (walls have same cost as free air). Then from here I created an average raster using the raster calculator and symbolized a certain cutoff. From here I used the raster to polygon tool on that cutoff of the average propagation raster to create a buffer like effect around the Wireless Access Point, and then extruded it for 3D purposes. Still not ideal, but the best that I have been able to come up with.